# Excel formula to check how many times a value fits in another until reaches the closest 100%

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Not sure if this is even possible.

I am trying to do something to calculate how many files of a specific sizes (59GB/71GB/74GB) can go into an HDD in a way that uses the most effective space.

For example, HDD1 has 10900 free GB how can I calculate a combination of how many 59GB and 71GB files fit on it to be as close of 100% used space as possible.

So far I have `=FLOOR.PRECISE(A2/K5)` where `A2` is the HDD size and `K5` is the file size and that tells me I can fit 184 files of 59GB in size on a 10900GB HDD, however, leaves 44GB of unused space.

So what would be needed would be for the formula to remove some of the 59GB values (from the 184 total) and replace them by how many 71GB files fit on the remaining empty space.

For example if 1 59GB file is removed (183files of 59GB are left) and 103GB of free space, meaning 1 71GB file would fit, leaving 32GB free.
Repeating the above until no more space is left or no more possible combinations left.

Maybe by creating a cell that will display the remaining space and then use some sort of "if" function, saying something like if CELL X (remaining space) is higher than Y amount then remove 1 from the total files of 59GB (184-1) and add 1 file of 71GB, and repeat until the value of CELL X is equal or lower than Y

Is this even possible?

Many thanks for having a look.

Comment: This is known generally as the Knapsack Problem. There's quite a lot of existing literature on it that may be helpful. You could consider using Solver if working in Excel.

Comment: But what about the formatting of the media and files that just take only part of a sector so space is wasted there?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In Office 365 you could use this:

```
=LET(goal,10900,
     a,59,
     b,71,
     c,74,
     L,LAMBDA(L,SEQUENCE(goal/L)*L),
     x,L(a),
     y,TOROW(L(b)),
     z,TOROW(L(c)),
TOCOL(IFS(TOCOL(x+y)+z=goal,
          "("&TOCOL(x/a&"*"&a&")+("&y/b)&"*"&b&")+("&z/c&"*"&c&")"),2))
```

The formula starts by naming the `goal`, and the 3 values `a`, `b`, and `c`.

Then a lambda function `L` is declared to generate a sequence of the `goal` divided by the value of `L` then multiplied by the value of `L`, where `L` is not delared yet.

Then we name `x`, `y` and `z` and perform the lambda calculation described in `L` where the value of `L` equals `a`, `b` and `c` respectively.

These arrays are summed (transposed from the other, so each value gets summed with any count of the other array).

The result of this is one big array containing all possible sums including the 3 values with different multiples.

We then compare this array to equal the `goal`. If the value equals the goal, we use reverse engineering to calculate the number of times certain value `a`, `b`, and `c` were used to get to the correct sum result and return that as text.

[image]

We could also start the lambda sequence at 0, so we allow one or more values to not occur in the sum:

```
=LET(goal,10900,
     a,59,
     b,71,
     c,74,
     L,LAMBDA(v,SEQUENCE(goal/v+1,,0)*v),
     x,L(a),
     y,TOROW(L(b)),
     z,TOROW(L(c)),
TOCOL(IFS(TOCOL(x+y)+z=goal,
          SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TOCOL(IF(ISERR(x/x),"",x/a&"*"&a&" ")&IF(ISERR(y/y),"",y/b&"*"&b&" "))&IF(ISERR(z/z),"",z/c&"*"&c))," "," + ")),2))
```

And apparently this calculates faster:

```
=LET(goal,10900,
     a,59,
     b,71,
     c,74,
     L,LAMBDA(v,SEQUENCE(goal/v+1,,0)*v),
     x,L(a),
     y,TOROW(L(b)),
     z,TOROW(L(c)),
TOCOL(IFS(TOCOL(IFS((x+y)<=goal,x+y))+z=goal,
          SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TOCOL(IFS((x+y)<=goal,IF(ISERR(x/x),"",x/a&"*"&a&" ")&IF(ISERR(y/y),"",y/b&"*"&b&" ")))&IF(ISERR(z/z),"",z/c&"*"&c))," "," + ")),2))
```